# javascript 404 page custom redirect unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, html

code:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="index.html">Click Here to Back to Home Page</a> Or Wait <p id="time" style="display:inline">Five</p> Seconds......
<script>
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Four"},1000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Three"},1000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Two"},1000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="One"},1000);
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com"}",1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Not successful. What should i do??
Pls help. Thx.

Comment: What happens?  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTimeout`s are all queued up at once, so you need to specify the times taking that into consideration:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="index.html">Click Here to Back to Home Page</a> Or Wait <p id="time" style="display:inline">Five Seconds</p>......
<script>
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Four Seconds"},1000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Three Seconds"},2000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="Two Seconds"},3000);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="One Second"},4000);
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com"},5000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that `setTimeout()` is asynchronous.  It schedules some code to run at some time in the future.  The way your code is written, it looks like you expect `setTimeout()` to pause the execution of the JavaScript until the timeout has occurred, then continue to the next statement.  But, it doesn't work that way.  You've scheduled 5 lines of code to be executed in the future, each 1000ms in the future.

To resolve this, you could just increase the timeout on each statement to be 1000ms longer than the previous statement.  But, all that redundant code is not great. Instead, I'd use a recursive function to write the elements of an array once per second until the array is empty, then redirect:

```
var countEl = document.getElementById("time");
var count = ["Five", "Four", "Three", "Two", "One"];
(function countDown() {
    if (count.length) {
        countEl.innerHTML = count.shift();
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
    else {
        location.href = "http://tool-box.weebly.com";
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on the last line, an extra quote character:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com"}",1000);
// *******  you need to remove this character --------------------------^
```

Fixing that will allow your script to "work", except that the new page will load after only 1 second: for a countdown you need to specify longer intervals for each subsequent timeout or they'll all be queued to happen 1000ms after that code runs. `setTimeout()` doesn't pause execution of the current function or sleep, it just queues something up for later. So specify 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. as in the other answers.